# How to access find all controls and all components into form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, reflection

I have a window form which contain some Controls an some Components ( like DataTable, XPCollection etc). I would like find all Control Names and Component Names which used into this form.

Comment: Mind if I ask why you want to do this?

Comment: this.Controls will give you what you want. Iterate over it and see what you get.

Comment: Components don't have a Name property that's available at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could do,

```
List<string> ctrlNames = new List<string>();
FIndAllCtrls(ctrlNames , this.Controls);

private void FIndAllCtrls(ctrlNames, ControlCollection ctrlColl)
{
   foreach(Control ctrl in ctrlColl)
   {
      ctrlNames.Add(ctrl.Name);
      if(ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
         FIndAllCtrls(ctrlNames, ctrl.Controls);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this code does not return the form components eg DataTable component

Comment: What do you mean by DataTable component?

Comment: to get the list of components, use this.components.Components and iterate over it.

Comment: @Asdfg That only works at design-time.  At runtime `this.components` is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
    IEnumerable<Control> EnumControls(Control top)
    {
        Queue<Control> todo = new Queue<Control>();
        todo.Enqueue(top);

        while (todo.Count > 0)
        {
            Control c = todo.Dequeue();

            yield return c;
            foreach (Control ch in c.Controls)
                todo.Enqueue(ch);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it is explained in this node:
[Find components on a windows form c# (not controls)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171914/find-components-on-a-windows-form-c-sharp-not-controls)
It looks there is only way via Reflection available.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @mrun: The copying content from another stackoveflow thread looks to me very stupid. I wanted add there the link with comment only, but not allowed to me.

Comment: @VáclavŠvára, if it is your intension, then you should leave a comment instead of answer

Comment: @mrum for comment I have to have 50 reputation which are missing at the moment